# R vector operation doesn't uniquely evaluate random functions?

Tags: r, simulation

I'm doing some basic simulation work in R and have run across this issue:

I have a three-valued vector

```r
v <- sample(c("a","b","c"),
            size = 1000,
            replace = TRUE,
            prob = c(1/200, 1/450, 1-1/200-1/450))
```

so something like `v` = [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, a,. . .].

Depending on the value of the vector, a specific binomial RV should be evaluated. When I try to do it with vector operations, it seems like the `rbinom(.)` is evaluating only once for each vector value. So every "c" becomes a 1 or a 0 rather than getting a unique value for each "c". Specifically

```r
experiment <- ifelse(v=="a", rbinom(1, 1, 0.5),
              ifelse (v=="b", rbinom(1, 2, 0.3),
              rbinom(1,1,0.7)))
print(experiment)
```

Returns something like [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,...] or [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,...] due to `v` being mostly made of "c"s. This is not the desired result.

When I do this with loops, I get the expected result:

```r
experiment<-rep(NA, 1000)
for (i in 1:1000){
  if (v[i] == "c") {experiment[i] <- rbinom(1, 1, 0.5)}
  else if (v[i] == "b") {experiment[i] <- rbinom(1, 2, 0.3)}
  else if (v[i] == "a") {experiment[i] <- rbinom(1,1,0.7)}
}
print(experiment)
```

returns something like [1,1,0,0,1,0,1,...]. `rbinom(.)` is evaluated anew each time.

Two questions:

1. Can I force the vector operation to uniquely evaluate the rbinom function?
2. Is it worth it? In other words, my understanding is that R prefers to use vector operations to loops for reasons of computation efficiency. If I force a unique evaluation, are those advantages lost? Given how compute-intensive some of these simulations are likely to be, even general guidance here is helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: in the first case your rbinoms need to be `rbinom(1000, ...` not `rbinom(1, ...` and `rbinom(length(v), c(1, 2, 1)[factor(v)], c(0.5, 0.3, 0.7)[factor(v)])`

Comment: I believe that's different logic. I'm trying to replicate a single coin flip for each value in the vector and evaluate 1000 such cases. Not evaluate 1000 coin flips for each value in the vector. I'm expecting an output domain of {0, 1, 2 [only occasionally]} rather than {x | x>=1000}.

Comment: @rawr is right.  You are misinterpreting the documentation for `ifelse()` (or not reading it?)

Comment: @rawr: You are correct, and I am wrong. I appreciate the help.